# javascript form post to main window

Tags: javascript, forms, post

```
<button class="Button" onclick="NewTicket()">New Ticket</button>

<script language=javascript>
   function OpenPopup( url, winname, features )
   {
    if(winname==''){
     window.open( url, winname, features, false );
     return;
    }
    if ( !findWindow( url, winname, features ) )
    {
     var handle = window.open( url, winname, features, false );
     if ( handle != null ) handle.focus();
    }
   }

   function findWindow( url, winname, features )
   {
    var handle = window.open( '', winname, features, false );
    if ( handle != null )
    {
     if (( handle.location != 'about:blank' ) && ( handle.location != '' ))
     {
      handle.focus();
      return true;
     }
    }
    return false;
   }
function NewTicket(){
    OpenPopup('../Ticket/New.php', 'NewTicket', 'channelmode=0, directories=0, fullscreen=0, width=430, height=360, location=0, menubar=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=1, status=0, titlebar=1, toolbar=0', false);
}
</script>
```

Opening a pop-up form with this code. No problem on this. I want to post the form (../Ticket/New.php) back to this page again. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a name for your current window. Add following snippet on the page where you have the opening button, before your window opening functions.

```
<script>window.name = 'mainwindow';</script>
```

In your New.php add target attribute to your form with value set to 'mainwindow'

```
<form target="mainwindow">
```

Comment: I assume you want to close it after submitting the form, so it's going to be <script>document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function(){ window.close(); }</script> added in the popup code.

Comment: I used onclick="self.close()" on popup submit button. Thanks.